# Angular momentum commutativity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

I was reading about the angular momentum in quantum mechanics and I am wondering 
why different components of the angular momentum cannot be measured simultaneously.

Is there any explanation behind the non-commutativity and the relation $[L_i,L_j] = \mathrm{i}\hbar \varepsilon_{ijk} L_k$ or is it just an axiom of quantum mechanics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commutation relations between the angular momentum components
can be derived from

- the [canonical commutation relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation) between
  position and momentum:
  $[r_i, p_j]=i\hbar\delta_{ij}$
- and the definition of [angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum):
  $\vec{L}=\vec{r}\times\vec{p}$,
  or $L_i=\sum_{jk} \varepsilon_{ijk}r_j p_k$